# Can't access Api from angular container

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which contains several containers, two between them are an angular front application and a spring boot API. 
when running the docker-compose file I successfully access the angular app from my browser, but when I tried to access the API from the angular app (send post request), I got

```
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.
```

In my angular app I am calling the api using its alias defined in the docker-compose.

```
http://search-service:8080/
```

Any suggestions to fix this error?

Comment: Quick guess: since you opened your Angular app on your host, the alias of your service is not known and can't be resolved. You need to use its IP.

Comment: @pzaenger or localhost:8080 if the port is exposed to the host

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga Indeed, good point.

Comment: I am not using the host network so even localhost:8080 is not working. Is it a good practice to use an IP address in the angular source code to connect to the API especially when the back-end container IP address can change?  isn't there any other solution to automatically resolve this " alias- IP address" conversion issue.

Comment: @daliDV usually you are using environment.ts for dev settings like localhost and environment.prod.ts for prod settings with real host name

Comment: Using the container-private IP addresses is never a best practice.  You can't access them in many very common setups (from a different host, a native Windows or Mac host, ...) and they _do_ change routinely (whenever you delete and recreate the container).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue when I add --prod option to the `npm run build` command in the angular Dockerfile. But anyone knows the reason?